# Conditional Debit from Credits using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one table cryptotransactions in below structure where transactions are stored.

| ID | TRANSACTION_TYPEID | TRANSACTION_NAME | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 5 |
| 2 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 20 |
| 3 | 103 | bitcoin-transferred | -5 |
| 4 | 104 | bitcoin-lost | -10 |
| 5 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 55 |
| 6 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 8 |
| 7 | 104 | bitcoin-lost | -16 |
| 8 | 103 | bitcoin-transferred | -5 |

I want bitcoin-transferred only be debited from bitcoin-mined and bitcoin-lost can be deducted from bitcoin-received or bitcoin-mined which ever comes first.

**Below is the expected result**

| ID | TRANSACTION_TYPEID | TRANSACTION_NAME | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 0 |
| 2 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 0 |
| 5 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 49 |
| 6 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 3 |

Comment: Can you show a case where FIFO behavior is clearly defined?

Comment: Showing expected results for an input dataset NOT in your question is exceedingly Unhelpful. If your first example is insufficient to demonstrate all necessary behaviors, edit your question to include the expanded data set. The question should be consistent with itself, at the very least.

Comment: @MatBailie I have modified the question with more details.

Comment: The difference between expected and actual is due to the order of operations, as noted in the answer.  The FIFO behavior (of the answer) is currently based on the `received` and `mined` order, not on the `lost` and `transferred` order, and the `transferred` adjustments are done first (in `received` and `mined` order).  When I have a moment, I'll try to address that difference.

Comment: Is the data protected from the final state going negative?  For example, can the data ever show `start with nothing, mine 10, then immediately transfer 15`?

Comment: Yes it’s protected from going negative. Transfer is possible only if there is mined balance. if mine is 10, then they can transfer only 10, not more than that. So there won’t be negative. Similarly is the lost case also. It can be done only from mined/received balances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `PIPELINED` function and only read the table once:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION process_cryptotransledger
  RETURN cryptotransactionledger_ttype PIPELINED
IS
  transactions cryptotransactionledger_ttype;
  loss_amount INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT cryptotransactionledger_type(
           id,
           transaction_typeid,
           transaction_name,
           amount
         )
  BULK COLLECT INTO transactions
  FROM   cryptotransactionledger
  ORDER BY id;
  
  
  FOR loss IN 1 .. transactions.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF transactions(loss).transaction_name
         IN ('bitcoin-received', 'bitcoin-mined')
    THEN
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;

    loss_amount := transactions(loss).amount;

    FOR gain IN 1 .. transactions.COUNT
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN loss_amount >= 0;
      
      IF transactions(gain).amount <= 0
      OR (
         transactions(gain).transaction_name <> 'bitcoin-mined'
         AND transactions(loss).transaction_name = 'bitcoin-transferred'
      )
      THEN
        CONTINUE;
      END IF;
      
      IF -loss_amount >= transactions(gain).amount THEN
        loss_amount := loss_amount + transactions(gain).amount;
        transactions(gain).amount := 0;
      ELSE
        transactions(gain).amount := transactions(gain).amount + loss_amount;
        loss_amount := 0;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  FOR i IN 1 .. transactions.COUNT
  LOOP
    IF transactions(i).transaction_name
         IN ('bitcoin-received', 'bitcoin-mined')
    THEN
      PIPE ROW (transactions(i));
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

After defining the data types:

```sql
CREATE TYPE cryptotransactionledger_type AS OBJECT(
  id                 INT,
  transaction_typeid INT,
  transaction_name   VARCHAR2(30),
  amount             INT
);

CREATE TYPE cryptotransactionledger_ttype
  AS TABLE OF cryptotransactionledger_type;
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cryptotransactionledger (
  id, transaction_typeid, transaction_name, amount
) AS
  SELECT 1, 101, 'bitcoin-received',      5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 102, 'bitcoin-mined',        20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 103, 'bitcoin-transferred',  -5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 104, 'bitcoin-lost',        -10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 101, 'bitcoin-received',     55 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 102, 'bitcoin-mined',         8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 104, 'bitcoin-lost',        -16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 103, 'bitcoin-transferred',  -5 FROM DUAL;
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(process_cryptotransledger());
```

Outputs:

> | ID | TRANSACTION_TYPEID | TRANSACTION_NAME | AMOUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 0 |
> | 2 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 0 |
> | 5 | 101 | bitcoin-received | 49 |
> | 6 | 102 | bitcoin-mined | 3 |

---

## Update

If the table is large, then a more efficient solution may be to process it in batches (again, only reading from the table once) and to hold the gains in a separate collection and to pipe them as output as soon as they are fully processed:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_cryptotransledger
  RETURN cryptotransactionledger_ttype PIPELINED
IS
  CURSOR transactions_cur IS
    SELECT cryptotransactionledger_type(
             id,
             transaction_typeid,
             transaction_name,
             amount
           )
    FROM   cryptotransactionledger
    ORDER BY id;

  transactions cryptotransactionledger_ttype;
  loss         cryptotransactionledger_type;
  gains        cryptotransactionledger_ttype := cryptotransactionledger_ttype();
  gain         PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  OPEN transactions_cur;
  
  LOOP
    FETCH transactions_cur
    BULK COLLECT INTO transactions
    LIMIT 1000; -- Set the batch size to an appropriate level.
    
    EXIT WHEN transactions.COUNT = 0;
    
    FOR i IN 1 .. transactions.COUNT
    LOOP
      -- Process each item in the batch.

      IF transactions(i).transaction_name
           IN ('bitcoin-received', 'bitcoin-mined')
      THEN
        -- Store the gains.
        gains.EXTEND();
        gains(gains.LAST) :=  transactions(i);
        CONTINUE;
      END IF;

      -- Process each loss.
      loss := transactions(i);

      gain := gains.FIRST;
      WHILE gain IS NOT NULL AND gains(gain).amount = 0
      LOOP
        -- Pipe the fully processed gain rows
        PIPE ROW( gains(gain) );
        gains.DELETE(gain);
        gain := gains.FIRST;
      END LOOP;
      
      -- Update the first appropriate gain row(s) with the loss amount.
      WHILE gain IS NOT NULL AND loss.amount < 0
      LOOP
        IF gains(gain).amount > 0
        AND (
           gains(gain).transaction_name = 'bitcoin-mined'
           OR loss.transaction_name <> 'bitcoin-transferred'
        )
        THEN
          IF -loss.amount >= gains(gain).amount THEN
            loss.amount := loss.amount + gains(gain).amount;
            gains(gain).amount := 0;
          ELSE
            gains(gain).amount := gains(gain).amount + loss.amount;
            loss.amount := 0;
          END IF;
        END IF;
        gain := gains.NEXT(gain);
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE transactions_cur;

  -- Pipe the remaining gain rows.
  FOR i IN gains.FIRST .. gains.LAST
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (gains(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c8f6d9c9ef2691803c1dd22f11addeef)*

Comment: Thanks MT0 for sharing this approach.

Comment: @MT0 - Would this constitute an optimisation?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f281f96654a07abb8f325c5e77660e8  *(Reducing the number of records checked and skipped, making the nested loop 'less triangular'?)*

Comment: @MatBailie Maybe.... that was very similar to my initial solution and then I refactored it to a single query. It may or may not be an optimisation depending on what the limiting factor is: if the limiting factor is the time spent on IO then doing two selects may reduce performance; if the limiting factor is processing time and IO is not a significant factor then it may be faster. My guess is that (particularly for small data sets) the time spent parsing the query and on IO is going to be more significant than the overhead of the final processing. You would need to profile both and check.

Comment: @MatBailie I've updated it with a more optimised (and a more complicated) solution.

Comment: @rocketpicks - I recommend testing this updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

1. We can't mine or receive less than 0.
2. We can't transfer or lose amounts we don't have.

It wasn't clear what the FIFO behavior involves. A better test case might have helped there.

Here's an updated test case with the above data and then a slightly larger data set, plus a solution which attempts to introduce FIFO logic:

[The updated test case with more data and FIFO logic](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b510ee6140250130c6e814f4c2f8c47)

The following solution uses a few calculations to do the work.

In `cte1` we derive:

1. `run_mined` - the running sum (in id order) of type = 102 (mined amounts)
2. `tot_xfer`  - the overall total of type = 103 (transferred amounts)
3. `tot_lost`  - the overall total of type = 104 (lost amounts)

Then since transferred amounts can only be deducted from mined amounts, we do this next in `cte2`, adjusting amounts of mined rows.

If the total transfer sum is greater than the current running sum of a mined row, that amount is reduced to 0.  We've transferred all this amount.

If the total transfer sum is not greater than the current running sum of mined data, we deduct the transferred amount, no greater than the current mined amount for this row.

Any subsequent mined row is not touched, since there are no further transfers.

In `cte1b`, we calculate `run2_in`, which is the updated running sum of both `mined` and `received` amounts.  Note that `mined` amounts were adjusted in `cte2`.

`cte3` now performs a calculation similar to `cte2`, but this time adjusts both types `received` and `mined` (101 and 102) in FIFO order, based on the total remaining `lost` amount.

Finally, we select only the fully adjusted `received` and `mined` rows to display, along with the corresponding `id` to indicate the order in which the FIFO operations were performed.

The SQL:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
         SELECT a.*
              , SUM(CASE WHEN (transaction_typeid = 102) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS run_mined   
              , SUM(CASE WHEN (transaction_typeid = 103) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * amount) OVER ()            AS tot_xfer    
              , SUM(CASE WHEN (transaction_typeid = 104) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * amount) OVER ()            AS tot_lost    
           FROM cryptotransactionledger a
          ORDER BY id
     )
   , cte2 AS (
         SELECT a.id, a.transaction_typeid,  a.transaction_name
              , CASE WHEN transaction_typeid <> 102        THEN amount
                     WHEN run_mined  <= ABS(tot_xfer )     THEN 0
                     WHEN run_mined  + tot_xfer  >= amount THEN amount
                                                           ELSE run_mined  + tot_xfer 
                 END AS amount
              , run_mined 
              , tot_xfer 
              , tot_lost 
              , amount AS amount1
           FROM cte1 a
     )
   , cte1b AS (
         SELECT a.*
              , SUM(CASE WHEN (transaction_typeid IN (101, 102)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END * amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS run2_in     
           FROM cte2 a
     )
   , cte3 AS (
         SELECT a.id, a.transaction_typeid,  a.transaction_name
              , CASE WHEN transaction_typeid NOT IN (101, 102) THEN amount
                     WHEN run2_in    <= ABS(tot_lost )         THEN 0
                     WHEN run2_in    + tot_lost  >= amount     THEN amount
                                                               ELSE run2_in    + tot_lost 
                 END AS amount
              , run_mined 
              , tot_xfer 
              , tot_lost 
              , run2_in
              , amount1
              , amount AS amount2
           FROM cte1b a
     )
SELECT id, transaction_name, amount
  FROM cte3
 WHERE transaction_typeid IN (101, 102)
 ORDER BY id
;
```

Result using data from the original question (the trivial case):

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| id | transaction_name | amount |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | bitcoin-received |      0 |
|  2 | bitcoin-mined    |     10 |
+----+------------------+--------+
```

In the updated fiddle, an example with more data is provided:

The new data:

```
create table cryptotransactionledger as
    select  1 as id, 101 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-received'    as transaction_name,   5 as amount from dual union all
    select  2 as id, 102 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-mined'       as transaction_name,  20 as amount from dual union all
    select  3 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual union all
    select  4 as id, 104 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-lost'        as transaction_name, -10 as amount from dual union all
    select  5 as id, 101 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-received'    as transaction_name,  55 as amount from dual union all
    select 15 as id, 102 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-mined'       as transaction_name,   8 as amount from dual union all
    select 16 as id, 102 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-mined'       as transaction_name,  20 as amount from dual union all
    select 17 as id, 102 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-mined'       as transaction_name,  30 as amount from dual union all
    select 18 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual union all
    select 19 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual union all
    select 20 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual union all
    select 30 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual union all
    select 31 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -4 as amount from dual union all
    select 40 as id, 104 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-lost'        as transaction_name, -16 as amount from dual union all
    select 99 as id, 103 as transaction_typeid, 'bitcoin-transferred' as transaction_name,  -5 as amount from dual WHERE 1 = 0
;
```

The result:

```
+----+------------------+--------+
| id | transaction_name | amount |
+----+------------------+--------+
|  1 | bitcoin-received |      0 |
|  2 | bitcoin-mined    |      0 |
|  5 | bitcoin-received |     34 |
| 15 | bitcoin-mined    |      0 |
| 16 | bitcoin-mined    |     19 |
| 17 | bitcoin-mined    |     30 |
+----+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks Jon for this detailed answer. This is awesome and this solution matches almost to my expected result. Only difference is that, in final result Amount for 3rd row i.e. ID 5 should have been 39 instead of 34 and Amount for 5th row i.e. ID 16 should have been 14 instead of 19. I think one of the bitcoin-transfer of amount 5 is incorrectly deducted from bitcoin-received (ID 5) instead of bitcoin-mined (ID 16). Bitcoin-transfer is allowed to be deducted from only Bitcoin-mined. In the main table data after ID 5 only 16 points are bitcoin-lost so when we deduct 55 - 16 we get 39.

Comment: @rocketpicks That was intentional, since the `transferred` amounts were executed first, and removed from the `mined` rows.  All of the `-5` amounts were related to `transfers` and needed to be taken from `mined` rows.  I'm not sure how any of those rows impacted a `received` row.  I'll review.  This shouldn't be hard to find.  The results are as I expected.  Maybe you wanted a slightly different order of operations.  We'll need to find that difference.

Comment: @rocketpicks To be clear, this wasn't entirely FIFO, since I processed all the `transfers` first, without regard to `lost` cases.  If we want to do them all at once, that's doable, but that also might lead to `lost` cases being subtracted from `mined` rows, leaving no option to handle some of the `transfer` cases (in FIFO order).  If you're assuming all that is always safe, we can adjust all of these to be handled within the same `CTE` term in strict FIFO order.  **The general approach should be usable, however.**

Comment: At row no 5 in the table we have `received` 55. After that only one `lost` is there of amount `-16` and remaining all are `transferred`. So if we have taken all `transfers` from `mined` rows, then row no 5 will not become `34` right? `received` - `lost` i.e. `55` - `16` = `39`. I'm not sure how did an extra 5 got deducted from that making it `34`.

Comment: @rocketpicks There was a remaining 5 at id = 1, not just the 55 at id = 5, I believe. Check the result of `cte1b` and check the current `amount` column and the `run2_in` column.  `SELECT * FROM cte1b ORDER BY id;` ... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=173eb5136f7e553171aa89da8962717e    (last panel)

Comment: @rocketpicks Maybe you could create a few step by step test cases with data, and progressively add data carefully / slowly, showing the result of each test, until you find the first unexpected result.  Add those cases to the fiddle and then post the URL for review.  I think my result looks ok.  But that's because I've included some assumptions that might not match your requirement perfectly.  Before making further logic changes, let's be sure there's a real problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237672/discussion-between-rocketpicks-and-jon-armstrong).

Answer (score 2):

The following answer abuses recursion to implement a loop.

- It's probably better to write an actual loop...

This is because the FIFO rules mean that it's impossible to know in advance which `mined`/`received` records will have been decremented by a `lost` record.  They each `lost`/`transferred` record must therefore be fully processed, before the allocation for the next `lost`/`transferred` record can begin.

Then, I used the following logic...

- An `income` record is when the `transaction_typeid` is `101` or `102`.
- An `outgoing` record is when the `transaction_typeid` is `103` or `104`.
- If an `outgoing` is type `104`/`lost`, it can be applied to ***any*** `income` type.  Else, the `outgoing` must be type `103`/`transferred` and can only be applied to `income` type `102`/`mined`.

Then...

- Create a record set of all `income` records
- Join the `outgoing` records to that set one at a time *(lowest `id` first)*
- The most that can be allocated to the first `income` record is `LEAST(in.amount, out.amount)`
- For the 2nd record, that becomes `LEAST(in.amount, out.amount - <amount allocated to row1>)`

Using window functions, that becomes *(pseudo-code)*...

```
LEAST(
  in.amount,
  GREATEST(
    0,
    out.amount - SUM(in.amount) OVER (<all-preceding-rows>)
  )
)
WHERE out.transcation_type_id = 104
   OR  in.transaction_type_id = 102
```

So, the final *(quite long)* query is...

```
WITH
  income
AS
(
  SELECT
    c.id,
    c.transaction_typeid,
    c.amount
  FROM
    cryptotransactionledger  c
  WHERE
    c.transaction_typeid IN (101, 102)
),
  outgoing
AS
(
  SELECT
    o.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.id)  AS seq_num
  FROM
    cryptotransactionledger  o
  WHERE
    o.transaction_typeid IN (103, 104)
),
  fifo(
    depth, id, transaction_typeid, amount
  )
AS
(
  SELECT 0, i.* FROM income i
  ---------
  UNION ALL
  ---------
  SELECT
    f.depth + 1,
    f.id,
    f.transaction_typeid,
    f.amount
    -
    LEAST(
      -- everything remaining
      f.amount,
      -- the remaining available deductions
      GREATEST(
        0,
        CASE WHEN o.transaction_typeid = 104 THEN -o.amount
             WHEN f.transaction_typeid = 102 THEN -o.amount
                                             ELSE 0         END
        -
        -- the total amount from all preceding income rows
        COALESCE(
          SUM(CASE WHEN o.transaction_typeid = 104 THEN f.amount
                   WHEN f.transaction_typeid = 102 THEN f.amount
                                                   ELSE 0         END
          )
          OVER (ORDER BY f.id
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                             AND         1 PRECEDING
          ),
          0
        )
      )
    )
  FROM
    fifo     f
  INNER JOIN
    outgoing o
      ON o.seq_num = f.depth + 1
)
SELECT
  f.*
FROM
  fifo  f
WHERE
  f.depth = (SELECT MAX(depth) FROM fifo)
ORDER BY
  f.id
;
```

Here's a demo, based on the one in you question.

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f5e6510fdea80e547252513f6397b43

Comment: Thanks MatBailie but I think this query also gives the same result 0,0,44,8. Solution by Jon also gives me this result but my expected result is 0,0,49,3.

Comment: @rocketpicks There was a typo in my `CASE` expression, 101 should have been 102 (it was deducting `transfered` from `received` rather than from `mined`) I have updated the answer and fiddle now.

Comment: @rocketpicks I'd be intrueged as to the setup you profiled this with. I'd have expected MT0's answer to be most efficient on larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the same logic as my recursive CTE, but written as a pure loop.

- The recursive CTE would fail after 2000 `outgoing` records.

Create a temp table to hold the values being worked on...

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE temp_cryptotransactionledger (
  id                  INT,
  transaction_typeid  INT,
  transaction_name    VARCHAR2(32),
  amount              INT
);
```

Loop through each `outgoing` record, and apply the FIFO logic...

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_outgoing IS
    SELECT id, transaction_typeid, amount
      FROM cryptotransactionledger
     WHERE transaction_typeid IN (103, 104)
  ORDER BY id;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO temp_cryptotransactionledger
    SELECT c.*
      FROM cryptotransactionledger c
     WHERE c.transaction_typeid IN (101, 102);

  FOR o
  IN cur_outgoing
  LOOP
    MERGE INTO
      temp_cryptotransactionledger  t
    USING
    (
      SELECT
        i.id,
        LEAST(
          i.amount,
          GREATEST(
            0,
            i.amount - o.amount - SUM(i.amount) OVER (ORDER BY i.id)
          )
        )
          AS amount
      FROM
        temp_cryptotransactionledger  i
      WHERE
            i.id     < o.id
        AND i.amount > 0
        AND (
             o.transaction_typeid = 104
          OR i.transaction_typeid = 102
        )
    )
      f
        ON  (t.id = f.id)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
      t.amount = t.amount - f.amount
    ;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Select out the results...

```
SELECT * FROM temp_cryptotransactionledger;
```

Demo...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7426efe17e9ee3cf3de61486cbdb865d

Comment: Thanks MatBailie. I’m wondering why would it fail after 2000 outgoing records. Could you please share more details regarding that.

Comment: Recursive queries are limited to a recursion depth of 2000.  They're not intended to be used for indefinite loops.

Comment: @MatBailie Please add a citation for that as it does not, at first glance, appear to be true [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ce6f7976fd3dc9029fd4f1cf2595b8e5)

Comment: @MT0 - I stand corrected. I don't know where I 'learned' the 2000 limit, but your fiddle objectively disproves it. Thank you.

Comment: @rocketpicks As per MT0's comment. My recursive CTE isn't limited in the ways that I thought. Whether the CTE or the loop suits you best will depend on your needs, trial both with real world data and see how it goes.